# AWS lambda getting 403 while calling a Rest endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf

As a context I have a Lambda defined in Java, that is calling a Rest endpoint in the same VPC. The client used for calling the API in java is: Apache-httpclient: 4.5.14.

Unfortunately the API isn't hit by this request(I've activated the debug level on all Http filters, and there isn't any signal). The request is failing much quicker..So the error response thrown from Cloudfront is 403 with a html page that is saying:

```
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Request blocked.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: ZXut71KzsyB0lwPoekzQzZBI8YiLtKwl2Uxx453epJWMYzWHybdPjQ==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

CloudFront logs:

```
2023-04-05 07:27:57 FRA6-C1 1269 3.126.58.253 POST d265tclvqdvre4.cloudfront.net /api/v1/private/ 403 - Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14%20(Java/11.0.18) - - Error JIZHPwJz60t6JnR1ghDicyohFuDw72napw1-WDoddtL4I453nhsU9w== some-host https 377 0.002 - TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 Error HTTP/1.1 - - 4147 0.002 Error text/html 919 - -
```

---

After some articles read in AWS, they suggested that maybe the WAF rules were blocking the request. And they were RIGHT ! I've looked in WAF log requests, and indeed that Lambda call was blocked due to IP not being part of the WAF rule.
After I've added that IP to WAF rule, in the logs it appeared that WAF allowed that request, but from CloudFront I still have another 403 error with the json message this time:

```
{"message":"Forbidden"}
```

Even this time the request is not hitting the API..But I'm not sure exactly where is failing ? This time CloudFront logs looks like this:

```
2023-04-05 12:01:15 FRA6-C1 394 3.126.58.253 GET d265tclvqdvre4.cloudfront.net /api/v1/private 403 - Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14%20(Java/11.0.18) - - Error MZkIxmogh5rBYGpo7VLXCg5-Cxxbh7PW4d5jruAPRqdDaeyygrOZvQ== some-host https 196 0.190 - TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 Error HTTP/1.1 - - 9465 0.190 Error application/json 23 - -
```

Beside this, some times I get a Connection timeout from Apache HttpClient which is set to 10 seconds. So it's either 403 from CloudFront OR ConnectionTimeout from Lambda.

---

If I run the Lambda as a junit from the Aws-Workspace machine, everything is working well. Is the Lambda missing any policy ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: Can you reach the API through CloudFront from Postman?  Can Lambda reach any other endpoint?  If the Lambda is indeed deployed in a VPC (which is not default, so I assume you know what you are doing), is it in a private or a public subnet?

Comment: Yes, I can call that API from Postman. Nope, I've tried other endpoints to access from the lambda, and I have the same 403 error. Only locally if I'm triggering the lambda(that points to the same API) is working..

Comment: Do you have to have the Lambda deployed in your own VPC?  By default, it is deployed in an AWS's VPC

Comment: @AlexChadyuk If I don't deploy it in the application VPC, I receive the error: 403 with the message: Request blocked(it's the html error response that I've posted above)

Comment: If I choose the application VPC, the error is still 403, but with the body: {"message":"Forbidden"}

Answer (score 1):

AWS WAF enabled at CloudFront (or API Gateway or ALB) has multiple rules to block HTTP requests based on headers or body.
In this case, Lambda function is using Apache HTTP library which is blocked in WAF due to user agent being identified as Bot or as a HTTPCategoryLibrary.

Please, try overriding the value of user-agent header in your REST client code to set it to that of any standard browser based client value for e.g. "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"